# Error 1004 in Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I have spent a few hours researching this Error 1004 problem here, but did not find a similar situation.

In an access module I have 3 global objects (global in the module only) as follows:

```
Private objXLapp As Excel.Application
Private objXLworkbook As Excel.Workbook
Private objXLworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
```

All are instantiated correctly.

I am transferring data from a table into a spreadsheet through a function that is repeatedly called from within the module. The bare bones of the routines are below.

```
Private Function CreateLevel2(ByRef rstCASHFLOW As DAO.Recordset, ByRef currentRow As Long, colRef As String) As Boolean
    Const PROC_NAME = "CreateLevel2"

    On Local Error GoTo CatchAllErrors

    Do
Retry:
        objXLworksheet.Range("C" & currentRow - 1).Formula = rstCASHFLOW!PMTlevel2Code

        ... other code here

        rstCASHFLOW.MoveNext
    Loop Until rstCASHFLOW.EOF

Exit_Func:
    On Local Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

CatchAllErrors:
    If Err.Number = 1004 then
        MsgBox "Press ok to continue"
        Goto Retry
    End If
    Set ErrorMessage.OrgError = err
    NewMsgBox eemUnknownError, MODULE_NAME, PROC_NAME
    Err.Clear
    Goto Exit_Func
End Function

Private Function CreateLevel1() As Boolean
    Const PROC_NAME = "CreateLevel1"

    On Local Error GoTo CatchAllErrors

    objXLworksheet.Range("B" & currentRow - 2).Formula = rstCASHFLOW!PMTlevel1Code

    … other code here

Exit_Func:
    On Local Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

CatchAllErrors:
    Set ErrorMessage.OrgError = Err
    NewMsgBox eemUnknownError, MODULE_NAME, PROC_NAME
    Err.Clear
    GoTo Exit_Func
End Function
```

If I remove the "On Error" the program stops at the line of code assigning a value to the worksheet in the Function "CreateLevel2". If I exam all variables, none have lost scope and are valid. If I then tell the program to resume, it continues with no problem and the correct data is transferred to the spreadsheet.

If I include the "On Error" to catch the error and pop up a msgbox asking me to proceed (effectively suspending execution until I press ok), the code continues without any problems.

Is this just some querk of Access VBA?

When the error occurs, the variable currentRow is 13, the table variable rstCASHFLOW!PMTlevel2Code has a value (a string) and rstCASHFLOW.EOF is false. The XL objects are also ok. Checking through the Watch Window shows me that the object references are all fine.

Note there is only one objXLapp, one objXLworkbook and one objXLworksheet. The workbook only contains 1 worksheet.

I am totally stumped!

Can anyone help... thanks

Comment: try a `objXLworksheet.cells(<row>, <column>).formula` instead. I suppose there is a chance that range address is being read as xlR1C1 syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but the error still persists.

I forgot to add the call in the first procedure "CreateLevel2 rstCASHFLOW, currentRow, colRef

Comment: try `objXLworksheet.Range("C" & currentRow - 1).Formula = chr(39) & rstCASHFLOW!PMTlevel2Code` then look at the result.

Comment: What I have found is that I need to alternate between using ".Value" and ".Formula" on the left side of the assignment. Even for numbers, I find I cannot use ".Value" and must resort to ".Formula = "+" & variable. Every string now requires a single quote mark. What I don't understand is that these problems do not occur until after the routine is called for the 3rd or 4th time.

All I can assume is that there is some inherent problem with VBA - the data does not change